# Is it safe to use Vcc from processor side or use another supply

Tags: opto-isolator

I have a [Toradex Carrier Board](http://docs.toradex.com/100145-colibri-arm-iris-carrier-board-perpective-651x448.png). It has few GPIO pins. I need to use them as inputs. In our application we will give 12v input but as the pins can only take 3.3v so I have to design a simple board which will contain `optocoupler` for isolation and will pass on 3.3v. Circuit will be like below:

[image]

Now I am confused with the pin number 3 & 4. I need 3.3v so what I have decided is to use the 3.3v of the processor. So is it safe to use the 3.3v from processor or should I use a regulator to convert 12v to 3.3v and feed that 3.3v to pin 4.

Comment: If you have doubts about the MCU's VCC, why don't you have the same doubts about the MCU's GND?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would connect pin 3 to MCU ground, and pin 4 to one of the MCU logic inputs. In most MCUs, you can set a digital pin internally to "pull-up", so the input is pulled high by the internal pull-up resistor, and then when your opto-isolator is activated, it pulls DOWN against the MCU pull-up resistor.

If your MCU doesn't have internal pull-up, then you can use an external resistor from pin 4 up to MCU VCC.

Comment: What's wrong with the pull-down configuration in the OP's schematic?

Comment: The pull-down configuration is probably more complex (requiring more parts) than exploiting the (likely) built-in pull-up resistor on the digital input pin.  And it is also likely a lower power load because 1K is a pretty stiff static load simply for a pull-down function. In a mains-powered circuit, this may be insignificant. But it would be wasteful in a battery-operated product. And it might even have implications of generating noise on the power supply bus, requiring additional filtering/bypass capacitors, etc.

Comment: Note that the GPIOs of most the SoCs used on Toradex System-on-Modules can be configured for internal pull-up or pull-down.  As an example, the [device tree pinmux documentation for the Colibri Vybrid (VFXX)](http://developer.toradex.com/device-tree-customization#Pinmux_Vybrid) shows typical pin pull up/down selection (PUS) as:
 - 100 kOhm Pull Down
 - 47 kOhm Pull Up
 - 100 kOhm Pull Up
 - 22 kOhm Pull Up